# Dynamically build pic based on arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I am trying to generate those kind images [image: Aim]:

Since I have to generate a lot of "houses" which are placed over the whole images, it would be nice if I could use `\pic` and give the names per argument.

I would be happy if the "house label" and the "flats" are nodes which I  can refer to (e.g. to draw arrows). It would be even better to have a third argument to color the different flats (so let's say Ben's flat is red and Anna's is green).

If there is another possibility than  `\pic` I am also open to it.

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

% define house node
\tikzset{pics/house/.style 2 args={code={
            \node[rectangle, draw = red, fill = green, minimum width = 4 cm, minimum height = 0.5 cm] (#1) {#1};
            
            
            \foreach \x [count = \i] in {#2}
            \ifthenelse{\ifodd\i}{
                \node[rectangle, draw = red, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.5 cm] at(#1) [xshift = -2cm, yshift = 0.5cm] (\x) {\x};
            }{
                \node[rectangle, draw = red, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 0.5 cm] at(#1) [xshift = 2cm, yshift = 0.5cm] (\x) {\x};
            }
                
            
        
        }}
        
}

\begin{document}                        
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\draw pic at(0,2) {house={House one}{Peter,Anna,Lisa}}

\draw pic at(0,2) {house={House two}{Robert,Ben,Jessica,Sophie}}

% Or with 3 arguments
\draw pic at(0,2) {house={House two}{Robert,Ben,Jessica,Sophie}{red,green,blue,grey}}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `matrix` could be an alternative to `pic`. Following code, shows a `matrixhouse` style which defines main options for the matrix. It has one argument which is the label. In this case the label is not attached to the building but it's easy to change it.

As building are defined with a `matrix`, all particularities can be added when you need it. Take a look at second floor in third building. And if you forget them, it's also possible to add later on, like in Patrick's apartment.

Every apartment is a particular node with individual name. The main difficulty could be that flats start to count by the top.

\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

```
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, backgrounds}

% define house node

\tikzset{
    matrixhouse/.style={matrix of nodes, 
        matrix anchor = south, 
        nodes={draw=red, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=.5cm},
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        label={[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=red, fill=green]below:#1},
        },
}
        
\begin{document}                        
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\matrix[matrixhouse={House one}] (one) {Ben & Anna \\ Peter & Lisa\\};

\matrix[matrixhouse={House two}] (two) at (5,0) {Sophie & \\ Robert & Patrick\\};

\matrix[matrixhouse={House three}, row 2/.style={nodes={fill=cyan}}] (three) at (10,0) {Jessica \\ Michelle & Simone \\ Francis & Rick \\};

\draw[->] (one-1-1)--++(90:1cm)-|(three-1-1.north);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[red!30] (two-2-2.south west) rectangle (two-2-2.north east);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is exactly what i needed. Thanks